# I get this error. Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a store with a register/signin page and I got a dispatch error that says I imported or exported the dispatch wrong. I tried fixing it the import but I still can fix the problem.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Store } from '../utils/Store';

  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Store);
  const { userInfo } = state;

  const submitHandler = async ({ name, email, password, confirmPassword }) => {
    closeSnackbar();
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      enqueueSnackbar("Passwords don't match", { variant: 'error' });
      return;
    }
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('/api/users/register', {
        name,
        email,
        password,
      });
      console.log(data)

      dispatch({ type: 'USER_LOGIN', payload: data });
      console.log(dispatch())
  };
```

The dispatch give me the above error and I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: What is `console.log(dispatch())` supposed to do?

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).